# Inserting data through GUI into sql server

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, user-interface, interface

I'm able to execute sql statements by writing the sql codes (Insert etc) on Eclipse and it is being displayed into sql server correctly. Connection has been done. But what should I do when a user wants to add data through a GUI interface (text field) and the data need to get stored into the database automatically ??

my code in the ADD button, but i'm getting the Error: java.lang.NullPointerException ! Help please..

```
try {
       String pid = ProductID.getText();
       String sql = "insert into Products_tbl values (' " +pid + " ')";

       // Running the sql query
       rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

       int count = 0;
       while (rs.next()) {
         count = count + 1;
       }

       if (count == 1) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome");
       } 
       else if (count > 1) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Duplicate User Access Denied");
       }
       else {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " User Not Found ");
       }
}

catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex); 
}
```

Comment: Sql Injection warning https://xkcd.com/327/  `(' " +pid + " ')";`

Comment: Can you debug to see which line give you that error?

Comment: Divide and conquer.  Write completely separate processes.  One process reads from and writes to the database.  Test this database process thoroughly.  The other process creates and processes the Swing GUI.  Test this GUI process thoroughly.  Connect the two processes.  Test this connection thoroughly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Using `(' " +pid + " ')"` is not safe because SQL injection may occur. Use SqlParameters instead. Please check:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

2- I am pretty sure something is wrong with the line: `rs = st.executeQuery(sql);`
Here, I bet the value of `st` is null. Make sure that your connection variable is defined and set correctly and you created the statement like below:

```
st = connection.createStatement();
```

You can also try executeupdate(query) instead of executequery(query) like:

```
int flag = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29

3- Please use `printStackTrace()` method while printing the error in the catch blog, the error message would be more understandable.

```
System.out.println("Error: " + ex.printStackTrace());
```